# python/lxml - find tag in html and change it

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, lxml

How do I search a html document for a tag when using lxml? I try to get all "span" tags in my document but I only get an empty list.

```
oldHtml = open("test.html", "r").read()
doc = etree.HTML(oldHtml)
print(doc.findall("span"))
```

After I find the Element I want to change the CSS of it and get the result as a new html document.

The html document is a copy of a random instagram user site

Comment: Try `doc.findall("./span")`

Comment: @Philipp I still get an empty list

Comment: That must be because your span tags are on a deeper level. `for elem in doc.iter():
    elemList.append(elem.tag)` What about a structure like this?

Comment: @Philipp nevermind, I fixed it by using `doc.findall(".//span")`